# Notification not show icon in case of using mipmap

Tags: android, push-notification, android-drawable, android-mipmap

I am handling FCM and Add these metadata to define icon and color for Notification  when i use mipmap icon it does not work and display filled rectangle
when I use drawable image it is being displayed

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />




    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/map_hot" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

with  mipmap
[image: with mipmap]

with drawable

[image: with drawable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is Notification icons must have transparent background [more explanation](https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/)

Solution:
if you have not a designer you can use 
this link [Image to transparent](https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png) to get image with transparent background then you use this to get all drawable dimensions 
[get image drawables](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html)